# delay time for the menu items to display its subitems

Tags: html, css

At the moment, my site displays the menu items horizontally and when the user hover over each one, its submenuitems are displayed. However, by the time the user tries to click on the subitem, they disappear. Is there any way I could delay the time in which the subitems are visible?

Comment: Submit some code. So we get to know how your menu works.

Comment: If the problem is that menu items disappear when you try to click them, there is something wrong with the way you are doing it, and adding a delay is not the way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible (using CSS3 transistions/animations) to add a delay on this show/hide behaviour but I think the trouble is to do with:

1. How you've nested your tags
2. Which tags have the associated :hover styles

If a user moves their mouse off the container element, the submenu is getting hidden again. They need to stay in the 'target area' of whichever element has associated :hover styles for child elements to be displayed. (I presume you're doing the show/hide of the submenu via CSS only.)

Really though, you need to give a code example in order to give specific feedback.